# How to get property of a class using GetValue

Tags: vb.net

I have a couple of classes with properties.  I would like to be able to iterate through the properties of the class and get the value of the property.  I included a sample of the class along with how I am looping the properties.  Need help with understanding the usage of "GetValue" and "SetValue"

```vb
Private Sub loadValues()
    Dim mySample As New Sample
    Dim props As PropertyInfo() = mySample.GetType().GetProperties()

    mySample.Test2 = True
    Console.WriteLine(mySample.Test2)

    For Each prop In props
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name)
        'This will loop through all the properties in the Sample clasee
        'How can I get and change the value of each of the properties?

        prop.GetValue(mySample, Nothing) '?????
        prop.SetValue(mySample, False, Nothing) '?????
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is the sample of the class

```vb
Public Class Sample
    Public Name As String = "Sample"
    Public _Cut As Boolean = False
    Private _Test1 As Boolean
    Private _Test2 As Boolean
    Private _Test3 As Boolean
    Public Property Cut(ByVal CabType As String) As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Cut
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Cut = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Test1() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Test1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Test1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Test2() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Test2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Test2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Test3() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Test3
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _Test3 = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Why do you have a property named Cut with a parameter that you don't use?

Comment: This example is a shortened version.  In the working property, the parameter is used.  I just shortened the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cut` property is indexed, so you need to pass some index value to `PropertyInfo.GetValue`. You may see that the signature of `GetValue` is

```vb
Public Overridable Function GetValue(obj As Object, index() As Object) As Object
```

so the index argument needs to be an array when indexed. Simply pass your `Nothing` as a single element index `{Nothing}` in that case. You can tell if there are index parameters by checking if `PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()` has anything

```vb
Private Sub loadValues()
    Dim mySample As New Sample
    Dim props As PropertyInfo() = mySample.GetType().GetProperties()

    mySample.Test2 = True
    Console.WriteLine(mySample.Test2)

    For Each prop In props
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name)
        If prop.GetIndexParameters().Any() Then
            prop.GetValue(mySample, {Nothing})
            prop.SetValue(mySample, False, {Nothing})
        Else
            prop.GetValue(mySample, Nothing)
            prop.SetValue(mySample, False, Nothing)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However, having an indexed property then iterating through all the properties arbitrarily may not make sense when you need to pass a specific index to properly access the property.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I will also make use of  If prop.GetIndexParameters.Length = 0 Then

All properties I will be looking through will all be made up the same way.  I have multiple classes that have different numbers of property counts

Comment: @user3786542 I'm thinking about this, and it works in your case when there is one indexer, but not quite accurate since if there are >1 then you would need to pass `{Nothing, Nothing, ...}` according to the count. But if you will ignore those with indexes then it doesn't apply anyway. Glad it helped